# Mongoose doesn't connect Mongo Db Atlas

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a simple node express app and I just try to connect to my MongoDB atlas. But It pulls this error. I also deleted node_modules and download all packages again but it doesn't work.

I get this error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')

I just import mongoose at start of the page like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

And that is my connection function:

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL as string, { autoIndex: true, dbName: 'personal-blog' });
    console.log('connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB may ignore fields set to undefined, but Mongoose doesn't as it has a schema to work from and will try and cast values to the right types as defined in the schema.

Comment: Should I create model?

Comment: can you try this way : try {
mongoose.connect( uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () =>
console.log("connected"));    
}catch (error) { 
console.log("could not connect");    
} and make sure yes the schema is manually created just in case

Comment: I just get typescript error like this  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'ConnectOptions'

Answer (score 0):

I just add this for options:

```
autoIndex: true
```

it works